# Paste excel charts into a power point template

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm very new to VBA in Excel. I have a few charts in excel that I want to automatically paste into a ppt template. Like charts `1` and `2` into slide `7`, charts `3` and `4` into slide `9`, etc.

I managed to open my template, but got stuck when copying the charts. Here is how I started it, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub CreatePowerPointTemplate()
    Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    strpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\My_template.pptx"
    PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open (strpath)

    ' get chart #5 and copy it into slide #7
    Set cht = Worksheets("Graphs").ChartObjects(5)
    cht.Copy
    PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing Early and Late Binding. This **Late binding** code works for me just fine. Add `Option Explicit` on top of your code. See what happens?

```
Option Explicit

'~~> If you are using late binding then you need to specify the value
'~~> of the power point constant without which Excel would not know
'~~> what this is...
Private Const ppPasteMetafilePicture As Integer = 3

Sub CreatePowerPointTemplate()
    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Dim PowerPointPrsn As Object
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim strpath As String
    
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    strpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\My_template.pptx"
    Set PowerPointPrsn = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(strpath)

    ' get chart #5 and copy it into slide #7
    Set cht = Worksheets("Graphs").ChartObjects(5)
    cht.Copy
    DoEvents '<~~ Give time to excel to place the object in the clipboard
    
    PowerPointPrsn.Slides(7).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture
End Sub
```

And here is an **Early binding** example. You need to set reference to *Microsoft Powerpoint Object xx.xx* library through **Tools->References**

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePowerPointTemplate()
    Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PowerPointPrsn As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim strpath As String
    
    strpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\My_template.pptx"
    
    Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set PowerPointPrsn = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(strpath)

    ' get chart #5 and copy it into slide #7
    Set cht = Worksheets("Graphs").ChartObjects(5)
    cht.Copy
    DoEvents
    
    PowerPointPrsn.Slides(7).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much. 
Using the Explicit Option, which I prefer, I get Run-time error '1004' on the line cht.Copy....it looks like the method Copy is not recognized. Anything else I should set??

Comment: `Option Explicit` and `Run-time error '1004'` are not related. Put a breakpoint on `cht.Copy` and check if `Cht` holds the chartobject?

Comment: I put a breakpoint and Quick Watch on the variable cht. The type is ChartObject/ChartObject. Unfortunately I cannot paste here a screenshot

Comment: Ok when there is a breakpoint, press F8 to step through the next line, what happens?

Comment: I get Run-time error `1004`: Application-defined or object-defined error.       But the cht variable is defined on the top as you suggested "Dim cht As ChartObject"

Comment: That is strange. The code works just fine for me. Possible to see your file? Just the excel file

Comment: sure, how can I share it from here?

Comment: Upload it on www.wikisend.com and then share the link here? Yuo can also put it in dropbox and share the link here. basically use any free file sharing site

Comment: works fine for me. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9943gs2wx8rp4b8/Animation.gif?dl=0 Will delete this link after you respond.

Comment: ok. So there must be some wrong setting in my Excel...I guess. I get the error: http://wikisend.com/download/955386/Animation.gif

Comment: What happens when you use the code in Module 4?

Comment: I usually do not do this but do you have teamviewer?

Comment: please delete the above comment. do not share your password and id like this.